# Use GitHub for Windows for GitLab project when the GitLab account is setup through GitHub

Tags: github, gitlab, github-for-windows

I an account on GitLab that was created using the sign in through GitHub option. When I attempt to connect a repository hosted on GitLab using the GitHub for Windows (GHfW) application, it asks for my username and password for GitLab. The problem is I technically don't have a username and password for GitLab. On the off chance it would work, I tried using my GitHub username and password, but that doesn't work.

I haven't been able to find anything that solves this issue. Is there anything I can do to get the GHfW application to work with this account and repository?